# Laravel and performing logic on a model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, solid-principles

I'm trying to adopt SOLID principles in my app.

Say I have these 2 models:

**Client** (fields=`id`, `name`, `address` etc) which *hasMany*:

**Holdings** (fields=`id`, `client_id`, `ticker`, `holding_date`, `value`)

In my ClientsController I might have a method like so:

```
public function show($id)
{
 $client = Client::find($id);
 $client->setValuations();
 $valuations = $client->getValuations();    

 return View::make('clients.show')-with(compact('client', 'valuations'));
}
```

So in the controller I want to get the valuations over time for the client. The `setValuations()` on my client model performs a fairly complex query which sums the holdings for a client and sets the resulant collection as a property on the client.

So my client model might look a bit like:

```
class Client extends \Eloquent {

 // All the usual model stuff

 protected $valuations;

 public function setValuations()
 {
  $this->valuations = DB::table('holdings')
        ->select('holdings.holding_date', DB::raw('SUM(holdings.value) AS sumofvalue') )
        ->where('holdings.client_id', $this->id)
        ->where('holdings.holding_date', DB::raw('LAST_DAY(holdings.holding_date)') )
        ->groupBy('holdings.holding_date')
        ->orderBy('holdings.holding_date', 'asc')
        ->get();
        return $this;
 }

 public function getValuations()
 {
  return $this->valuations;
 }
}
```

As we can see this is a fair amount of crap to put in a model (and I have condensed it a lot for the sake of brevity!). I should think that using a repository pattern might be the best approach but I'm unsure of how to structure this. Assuming I have several client-related attributes that need a fair amount of querying or processing to determine what they are (such as *returns*, *transactions in client currency* - this would require applying fx conversion to a collection of values, for example), how would be the best way to structure this and where should the logic be placed?

Answer (score 1):

You are absolutely right.  Keeping logic like this bloats the model and leads to violations of SOLID principles.  I use the repository pattern to move this kind of logic out of my model (who should not have that responsibility i.e. Single Responsibility Principle) and into a dedicated class. 
  I suggest you take a look at an open source project like the Laravel.io website that utilizes the repository pattern. After seeing their code you should be able to apply the pattern for yourself. Here is a link https://github.com/LaravelIO/laravel.io

I also highly recommend https://www.laracasts.com . SOLID principles and the repository pattern are thoroughly discussed and has drastically improved my understanding of Laravel and coding best practices.

Comment: Yes the repository pattern is the direction I'm going. I think for more complex processing I would further abstract this logic to a separate class (e.g. for calculating returns). I am an avid subscriber of laracasts so have been going through the relevant videos.